# how to repeat tensor elements with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Denote the hidden states of the phoneme sequence as Hpho = [h1, h2, ..., hn], where n is the length of the sequence. Denote the phoneme duration sequence as D = [d1, d2, ..., dn], where sum of di = m and m is the length of the
mel-spectrogram sequence.
 We denote the length regulator LR as Hmel = LR(Hpho, D, α), (1)
where α is a hyperparameter to determine the length of the expanded sequence Hmel, thereby controlling the voice speed.
 For example, given Hpho = [h1, h2, h3, h4] and the corresponding phoneme duration sequence D = [2, 2, 3, 1], the expanded sequence Hmel based on Equation 1 becomes [h1, h1, h2, h2, h3, h3, h3, h4] if α = 1 (normal speed). When α = 1.3 (slow speed) and 0.5 (fast speed), the duration sequences become Dα=1.3 = [2.6, 2.6, 3.9, 1.3] ≈
[3, 3, 4, 1] and Dα=0.5 = [1, 1, 1.5, 0.5] ≈ [1, 1, 2, 1], and the expanded sequences become
[h1, h1, h1, h2, h2, h2, h3, h3, h3, h3, h4] and [h1, h2, h3, h3, h4] respectively.

above text is from a paper FastSpeech TTS model. Here the Hpho sequence is a 3D tensor [batch_size, text_length, word_dim], the D sequence is 1D tensor [N]. how to imlement the target tensor Hmel? Hmel is also a 3D tensor [N, mel_length, word_dim]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work. But note that this only works for 1D tensors.

```
a = tf.constant([2,3,1,4]) 
b=tf.constant([1,2,1,2])

res = tf.concat([tf.tile([aa], [bb]) for aa, bb in zip(tf.unstack(a), tf.unstack(b))], axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(res))
```

Comment: what if a and b tensor has shape [None, None] when creating static graph?

Comment: @H.Gang Can you provide an example of what you expect? (Edit the question)

Comment: given Hpho = [h1, h2, h3, h4] and the corresponding phoneme duration sequence D = [2, 2, 3, 1], the expanded sequence Hmel becomes [h1, h1, h2, h2, h3, h3, h3, h4] if α = 1 (normal speed). When α = 1.3 (slow
speed) and 0.5 (fast speed), the duration sequences become Dα=1.3 = [2.6, 2.6, 3.9, 1.3] ≈
[3, 3, 4, 1] and Dα=0.5 = [1, 1, 1.5, 0.5] = [1, 1, 2, 1], and the expanded sequences become
[h1, h1, h1, h2, h2, h2, h3, h3, h3, h3, h4] and [h1, h2, h3, h3, h4] respectively.

Comment: @H.Gang can you add this as a part of the question and possibly more information? I didn't really get what you need.